# ASP.NET Server tags being rendered in IE6, IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, server-tags

I've got a weird issue where the ASP.NET closing server tags are being rendered on the page and I'm not able to figure what is causing this issue. There is nothing in between the body and the first div, which has an id="Page". There is no issue in other browsers. Do you have any ideas?

This is the code behind and what gets rendered in IE6, notice the server tags, right before the intial div.

[image: IE 6]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkIZ2.png

IE8 same issue, different place, and there is also a snapshot from inspecting the elements which confirms the place of the server tags (though that control uses another master page, that has a simillar structure - see code below).

[image: IE 8]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqjB6.png

Any ideas are good, cos at the moment I don't know what else to try. :) Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the reason, but you missed the final delimiter of the `href` in the `lt IE 9` `<link>`.

Comment: Yep, that was it! To be honest I've checked them a couple of times, and even tried other things before asking the question, but it seems I got too much used to the code and overlooked such a simple mistake. Thank you very much @StrubT for taking the time to read and answer my question. How do I give you reputation points for resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the final delimiter of the `href` in the `lt IE 9` `<link>`.

Just add the delimiter and everythings should work fine.